# Python regex multiple matches with grouping

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Input String

```
<msgCode>1111</msgCode>asdasdad<errorId>2222</errorId>
```

What I want

(1111,2222)

If I use   findall, this is what I get :

```
>>> import re;
>>> print re.findall("<(msgCode|errorId)>([0-9]+)</(msgCode|errorId)>","<msgCode>1111</msgCode>asdasdad<errorId>2222</errorId>");
[('msgCode', '1111', 'msgCode'), ('errorId', '2222', 'errorId')]
```

What I hope for is

```
[('1111','2222')]
```

Is there a easy way to do it using re  instead of post-processing output ?

Comment: you should really parse xml with an xml parser.

Comment: Yes, let's all pontificate using the same thread over and over again, even though the OP might be certain that his XML/HTML will never contain tags nested within themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using xpath instead:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> root = html.fromstring('<msgCode>1111</msgCode>asdasdad<errorId>2222</errorId>')
>>> root.xpath('//*[self::msgcode or self::errorid]/text()')
['1111', '2222']
```

Comment: This is the reason why I post SO questions, even when I have crude workaround such as post-processing the regex find. :) :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a Non-Capture group for the msgCode tags `(?:msgCode|errorId)`

```
>> import re
>> subject = "<msgCode>1111</msgCode>asdasdad<errorId>2222</errorId>"
>> result = re.findall("<(?:msgCode|errorId)>([0-9]+)</(?:msgCode|errorId)>", subject)
>> print result

['1111', '2222']
```

Comment: In my case this happened to be HTML, hence I selected another as answer.  But thank you for your answer Vasil. :)